# I need help with this definition of a partition of a closed interval [a,b]

Tags: calculus

[image]A partition of a closed interval I = [a,b] in R is a set of couples $(I_i,t_i)$ such that $t_i ∈ I_i$ for i = 1,...,n and I = $∪I_i$
So for [0,4] is ([0,3],{1},[2,4]{3}) a partition of [0,4]?
Is ([0,4],{2}) a partition? The reason for the first attempt is because we have $I_i$ as a subinterval of [0,4] so there can be more than one subinterval $I_i$ but I also know say $I_2$ can't be two subintervals so I am now confused.The only reasonable partitions for me here are ([0,4],$t_i$) where $t_i$ are subsets of [0,4] like {1},{2},(0,3) etc.
Is there a better explanation of this definition.

Comment: I would expect the $I_i$ to be disjoint expect perhaps at the endpoints to call it a partition. What is the context?

Comment: I am trying to calculate Reimann sums given partitions with tags at the right endpoints of the given partitions

Comment: Based on that context (but also because of the word “partition”), I am almost certain your definition is incomplete. Can you give the exact source of your definition (title, author, edition, and page number)? A link to a picture of the original definition might help too.

Comment: It is in my lecture slide from my teacher,the slide has no references and I am not able to send images as comments,is there a way i can post a link leading to it?

Comment: I got it on Google Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FALIknPaYpvDmxOQNyRg5_UpWBb0qf00/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: This kind of information does not belong in comments anyway. It belongs in the question, and you can put it there by editing the question. (Your Google drive link appears to be access locked.)

Comment: I have edited it into the question,thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt,
$$
\Big( [0,3], \{1\}, [2,4]\{3\} \Big)
$$
is not a partition in the defined sense, because it is an ordered triple, not a set of ordered pairs.

Your second attempt,
$$
\Big( [0,4],\{2\} \Big)
$$
is technically not a partition, because it is an ordered pair, not a set. Moreover, the second element should be just a number, not a set. The set you'd want is
$$
\Big\{ \big( [0,4],2 \big) \Big\}
$$

Some examples of partitions of $[0,4]$ would be
$$\begin{align*}
&\Big\{ \big( [0,1], 1 \big), \big([1,3],2\big), \big([3,4],3\big) \Big\} \\
&\Big\{ \big( [0,4], 0 \big) \Big\} \\
&\Big\{ \big( [0,2], 1 \big), \big( [1,4], 3 \big) \Big\}
\end{align*}$$
at least within the sense provided. A general partition of $[a,b]$ would look like
$$
\Big\{ \big( [a_1,b_1], t_1 \big), \cdots, \big( [a_n,b_n], t_n \big) \Big\}
$$
for some positive integer $n$, with $t_i \in [a_i,b_i]$ for all $i$, with the condition
$$
[a,b] = \bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]
$$
If you want to evaluate a function at the right-endpoint of the partition, you would choose $t_i = b_i$.

---

In my experience, this is a very unusual definition. The usual definition that arises in the context of Riemann integration is as so:

> A ***partition*** of $[a,b]$ is a set of finitely-many points $P := \{x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ such that
> $$
> a =: x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n := b
> $$

This is better, for several reasons:

- You're not trying to deal with ordered pairs. In fact, this notion of a partition cleanly divides $[a,b]$ into almost-disjoint intervals,
  $$
  [x_0,x_1] \quad [x_1,x_2] \quad \cdots \quad [x_{n-1},x_n]
  $$
  ("almost-disjoint" in that they only touch at the endpoints, which is more than good enough for the theory used).
- Disjointness (or almost-disjointness) is a nice property to have, since we don't have to worry about overlaps.
- It separates the notion of the tag from that of the partition, making it look like a freer choice. Trying to specify both at the same time just feels clunky, especially because many choices of tags $t_i$ will exist for any given partition, unless you choose to use a very narrow rule.

Comment: Okay,so given 
P1 := (0, 1, 2, 4)
P2 := (0, 2, 3, 4) 
P3:= (0, 1, 1.5, 2, 3.4, 4)
P4 := (0, 0.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4) if I want to find the reimann sum of $x^2$ with tags selected as P1 with the tags at the left endpoints of the subintervals how will it look like,I don't understand the tag in there and the definition of tagged partition seems similar to the first definition i gave,.

Answer (score 2):

Okay,I abundoned the idea of using this definition in solving the question I had and was able to solve it now using the definition of partition as $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b.$
the question I was attempting was to find the Reimann sum of $x^2$ with partitions $P_1 := (0,1,2,4)$
$P_2 := (0,2,3,4)$ and the tags are selected as indicated.
(a) P_1 with the tags at the left endpoints of the subintervals. 
$\textbf{Ans}$
the subintervals in $P_1$ are [0,1],[1,2],[2,4] and tags are $t_1=0$,$t_2=1$ $t_3=2$
so the Reimann sum is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i)(x_i -x_{i-1})$ where n=3 in this example,so evaluating that gives
f(0)(1-0)+f(1)(2-1)+f(2)(4-2)=0+1+4(2)=9

(b) $P_2$ with the tags at the right endpoints of the subintervals.
$\textbf{Ans}$
subintervals of $P_2$ are [0,2],[2,3],[3,4]
S(f,P)=f(2)(2)+f(3)(1)+f(4)(1)=4(2)+9(1)+16(1)=33.
$\textit{hope i am right}$

Comment: This seems like a good choice to me. The first definition **is** missing some information that the second definition provides. Also, the question seems to be stated using the notation of the second definition. I believe you have identified all the intervals and tags within the partitions correctly.